# Best Practices for Texturing Large Objects

Tags: textures, 3d-meshes, uv-mapping

[image]

Kind of a 3D graphics newbie here.  This is the biggest prop I've ever tried to texture, and I'm kind of stumped.  How do you get a decent resolution on large meshes like this without exporting enormous maps?  Texture atlases?  Tiling textures?  And what's the best way to set up the UVs, if so?

Comment: If that screenshot is from blender, then this might be more of a question for https://blender.stackexchange.com (Looks to me like that at first glance, but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse areas of the texture on more than one polygon to get more effective resolution out of a texture. That is pretty much the same concept as tiling a texture, except you're doing it by manipulating the UVs, rather than as a setting in the material/shader.

In your pictured model for example, you can easily have all the inset panel share the same portion of the texture. When assigning texture coordinates, simply have the UVs for those panels overlap. Now you only paint one panel on the texture image and poof! all the panels have that texture.

And yes I am talking about texture atlases, where every polygon in the model has UV coordinates mapping different parts of the texture image to that polygon.

For one visual example, refer to [the vertical columns in this tutorial](https://youtu.be/Z1MouKWH6IM?t=84). The wall with a bolt-thing only appears once in the texture image, but there are 4 columns sharing that image in the 3D scene.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's wondering, like me, how this changes for texturing levels, like for walls and stuff, here's another video I just found that talks about that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvUfry7gKvU

What this video explains is extending UVs outside the 0-1 texture space in order to tile the texture. Technically textures don't *have* to repeat like this, but they usually do. The rendering engine can set textures to repeat or clamp (the technical term for, well, staying in the box).

Comment: Can you summarize the main insights you gleaned from this video, so that this answer remains useful even if the video link becomes inaccessible in the future?